# Android: getSignInIntent() not creating login prompt

Tags: android

I have run into a bit of a roadblock trying to utilize Google Sign-in on an app I'm working on, and I can't seem to find any instances of somebody else having the same issue, so I suppose I have to bite the bullet and ask a question here...

I'm still learning, so forgive me if I'm missing something painfully obvious.

Basically, when the main activity starts, it's supposed to check if the user is already signed in with their account in onStart()

```
@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    @SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
    GoogleSignInAccount account = GoogleSignIn.getLastSignedInAccount(this);

    checkLogin(account);
}
```

If they're not, then they are supposed to be moved over to a separate login activity

```
private void checkLogin(@Nullable GoogleSignInAccount account) {
    if (account == null) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, LoginActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    }

    else {
        TextView spashText = findViewById(R.id.txt_splash);
        spashText.append(account.getDisplayName());
    }
}
```

The login activity is supposed to authenticate the user, start the main activity, and close itself, which I haven't even gotten far enough along to see if this will work. I'm hoping when the main activity performs its check again in onStart() it'll retrieve an account

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

private static final String TAG = LoginActivity.class.getSimpleName();
private static final int RC_SIGN_IN = 9001;

private GoogleSignInClient mGoogleSignInClient;
SignInButton signInButton;

@SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.login_screen);

    signInButton = (SignInButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_sign_in);
    signInButton.setOnClickListener(this);

    GoogleSignInOptions gso =
            new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_GAMES_SIGN_IN)
                    .requestEmail().build();

    mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if (view.getId() != R.id.btn_sign_in) return;

    @SuppressLint("RestrictedApi") Intent signInIntent = mGoogleSignInClient.getSignInIntent();
    startActivityForResult(signInIntent,RC_SIGN_IN);
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        @SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
        Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
        handleSignInResult(task);
    }
}

private void handleSignInResult (Task<GoogleSignInAccount> completedTask) {
    try {
        Log.d(TAG,"Entered try-catch block");
        GoogleSignInAccount account = completedTask.getResult(ApiException.class);
        Intent intent = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
    } catch (ApiException e) {
        Log.w(TAG, "signInResult:failed code=" + e.getStatusCode());
    }
}
}
```

But I can't get a sign-in dialog to show, the screen begins to dim as if if were about to display, and then it regains brightness, giving GoogleSignInStatusCodes #12501, which is not very descript in itself.
"public static final int SIGN_IN_CANCELLED

The sign in was cancelled by the user. i.e. user cancelled some of the sign in resolutions, e.g. account picking or OAuth consent.
Constant Value: 12501"

Logcat shows it getting ready to draw the dialog, then after that exception is thrown, it promptly destroys it.

I have provided my debug SHA-1 key in the API console along with the package name of the app of course, as well. I tried deleting it and re-adding it to no avail. Is there anything I need to add to the app itself for a login that doesn't talk to any back-end servers?

The exception is thrown here
`GoogleSignInAccount account = completedTask.getResult(ApiException.class);`

I'm Googled out, not too sure what step to take next...

Answer (score 2):

Ohh I found it, never noticed I accidentally put

`new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_GAMES_SIGN_IN)`

Changed it to the proper

`new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)`

And it works perfectly... whoopsies